# Use ORDER BY clause on foreign language field

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have some countries name in different languages in MySQL db table, table can support utf8. 
But the `SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY 'name_czech'` always sort English alphabatically order

[image]

[image]

My question is How could we sort records by foreign language field?

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: maybe you want to use backtick instead of single quote. how about `ORDER BY name_czech` ?

Comment: @ArashMilani the question is up there: `My question is How could we sort records by foreign language field?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you want to use backtick instead of single quote

```
SELECT * 
FROM countries 
ORDER BY `name_czech`
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand the question, or what you want to achieve, but i can guess by the sample that you are giving, that no ordering except the default mysql ordering takes place. In order to be able to order by a column, you want to use the backtick (`) characters. In some conditions, the " character is also allowed, although i doubt that's what you need.

Coming back to the sorting problem, if the name of the column means anything, then i guess those are names in czech. It matters what collation does the column has. If it is a utf8 czech collation, then the sorting will take place according to that. If not, you can always force a collation other than the one you've defined for the column using `ORDER BY name_czech COLLATE utf8_czech_ci` which will apply the sorting for the respective collation. If the column is utf8, you should have no more surprises.

Basicly, this comes back to either changing the collation for the column if is not the apropriate one (by alter table), or change the collation during the query.

Answer (score 0):

got it I just remove single quot on field name

```
select * from countries order by name_czech
```

Thanks to all friends.